# Cfmail and cftextarea not retaining line breaks

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I am working on a site that is having a problem with one of its mail forms. When a user enters text into a `CFTEXTAREA`, it doesn't retain any of the formatting (pressing 'enter' doesn't result in a line break). Not when its stored as a variable or emailed by a `<CFMAIL type="HTML" ..>`).

A site admin claims that it used to work fine. Any tips?

```
<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="No">
    <cfmail to="OMITTED" from="OMITTED" subject="#subject#" type="html">
       #message#    
    </cfmail>
</cfprocessingdirective>

<cfform name="mail" action="./mailinglist.cfm?sendMessage=true" 
       format="#type#" 
       height="400">

  <cfformgroup type="vertical">
      <table width="99%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
          <td class="form_label">Subject: </td>
          <td class="form_field">
               <cfinput class="textbox" required="yes" 
                    message="Please fill out the subject heading." 
                    style="width:200px;"  
                    type="text" 
                    name="subject" 
                    label="Subject:" width="200">
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="form_label">Message: </td>
          <td class="form_field">
                <cftextarea  class="textbox" required="yes" 
                       id="message" 
                       name="message" 
                       message="Please fill out the message body of the form..."
                       style="width:300px; height:150px;" 
                       width="350" height="250" 
                       label="Message:" 
                       wraptext="72" ></cftextarea>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="form_label"></td>
          <td class="form_field" align="left" valign="top">
               <cfinput class="textbox" disabled value="yes"  
                     type="checkbox" 
                     name="announcement" 
                     label="Post as Announcement?">
               &nbsp;Post as Announcement? 
          </td>
      </tr>
      </cfformgroup>
```

Comment: If you output the #message# variable to your browser, is the text formatted?

Answer (score 13):

To preserve line breaks from a textarea in an HTML-formatted email, you must replace the line breaks with `<br>` tags:

```
reReplace(message, '\n', '<br />', 'ALL')
```

If you don't have additional HTML-formatted content in your email message, you can simply remove the `type="HTML"` attribute from the CFMAIL tag, and the text from your text area will appear as it was entered with line breaks intact.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use @imthepitts answer but just to add some additional options you can also use

```
replace(message, chr(10), '<br />', 'ALL')
```

or

```
<cfmail type="html">
<pre>
#message#
</pre>
</cfmail>
```

**Note:** Markup, all left aligned intentionally to prevent unwanted indentation in the email.

Comment: If the only desired formatting is carraige returns, I think I like the <pre> tags answer the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a rich textarea.

```
<cftextarea name ="message" richtext="true"
other attributes
>
</cftextarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your CFmail, you can use `#paragraphformat(message)#` and that will keep your line breaks.

Comment: No it doesn't. A single line break = `&nbsp;`, 2 line breaks = `<p>` so a single line break does not put content on the next line as desired.